# How to enable shutdown timer?

Tags: 10.04, shutdown

Before I upgraded to 10.04 last spring, I remember having a timer counting down from 60 after clicking the shutdown button. This gave me a 60 second time frame to interrupt the shutdown in case I forgot to do something.

Since the upgrade this is gone and my system shuts down immediately when I click the button. Anyone who knows how to re-enable the timer?

Answer (score 2):

The timer is no longer an option. The rationale for the removal:

> Yes, this is by design. Basically, if the dialogs come up fast enough
>   it doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to have them count down as
>   well. People will see and respond to them. Thanks for noticing.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/548415

Comment: So basically the developers decided to just remove a functionality instead of adding the possibility to disable it with setup? That doesn't sound very logical. Does it? I think the scenario I described above is a good reason to keep that functionality available.

Comment: @KingWilliam I agree and so do a lot of other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-enable the timer, but you can have a shutdown confirmation dialog.

This is configured with the `/apps/indicator-session/suppress_logout_restart_shutdown` key in GConf.

You can start GConf Editor by launching the Run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and typing `gconf-editor` and then executing it.

Comment: I already have the confirmation dialog ;)